# display image with frame background - new to android

Tags: java, android, layout

in my xml layout, I have a [border](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=90D26B3C24DAF89C!121&authkey=!AMapg6QLzPcS5RY&v=3&ithint=photo%2Cpng) which I would like to place an [image](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=90D26B3C24DAF89C!122&authkey=!AFLVabhb4UQgkSo&v=3&ithint=photo%2Cjpg) in side of that border.

I have tried to use an imageView like this:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:background= name of border file
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="95dp" />
```

however it did not work, how would I implement this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the android:src attribute to specify your image, then use the android:background attribute to show the border. If you haven't done so already, you could convert your border image into a nine patch, so that it will only stretch the straight parts and not the round corners. If the android:src image entirely overlays the background image, then you can introduce some android:padding to clear the border.

Comment: that didnt work, both image displayed, but the broder did not wrap

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your background image is stored in a preferred location i.e.:

1. drawable-mhdpi
2. drawable-xhdpi
3. drawable-xxhdpi
4. drawable-xxxhdpi

Here is a straight forward solution.

```
 android:src="@drawable/your image name goes here"
```

Comment: Do mind sending me a link to some website of your own that shows what exactly you are talking about so that I can help. Because the solution I gave should have worked. To clarify a little more on your question. Did you want add a frame that is an image or what is that frame that your want to apply? That question confuses a little bit. I would like to help if I get those stuff right. Thanks